# Good text on Clinical Trials?

Tags: references, teaching, clinical-trials

I'm an undergraduate statistics student looking for a good treatment of clinical trials analysis. The text should cover the fundamentals of experimental design, blocking, power analysis, latin squares design, and cluster randomization designs, among other topics.

I have an undergraduate knowledge of mathematical statistics and real analysis, but if there's a fantastic text that requires a bit higher level of statistics or analysis, I can work up to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would definitively recommend [Design and Analysis of Clinical Trials: Concepts and Methodologies](http://books.google.fr/books?id=HXMUEjZ4vyAC&dq=Design+and+Analysis+of+Clinical+Trials:+Concepts+and+Methodologies&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=fr&ei=YQuTTPG-KseLswbt9JH5CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAw) which seems actually the most complete one given your request.

[Statistical Issues in Drug Development](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470018771.html) also covers a broad range of concepts but is less oriented toward design of experiment. [Statistics Applied to Clinical Trials](http://books.google.fr/books?id=LEDJ-6bPa8AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Statistics+Applied+to+Clinical+Trials&source=bl&ots=LwzvnasZuk&sig=OkDTIEnTaaONeDG5Ik1XVOhIeNM&hl=fr&ei=yAiTTNHoN8LEswbg2_D4CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ) includes more technical stuff, but mainly focus on crossover trials and applications in epidemiology. And there is always the most famous Rothman, [Modern Epidemiology](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Z3vjT9ALxHUC&dq=rothman+modern+epidemiology&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=fr&ei=MAmTTMF2zcuzBve20fgJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw), which provides valuable help for interpretation and examples of application of clinical biostatistics. Finally, [The Design and Analysis of Clinical Experiments](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471349917.html) is more centered onto the analysis of specific experimental settings, but it does not address other points and is a bit older.

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to go past Piantadosi's [Clinical Trials: A Methodologic Perspective](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471727814) at least as a starting point. It is quite comprehensive and covers the topics you want and much more - including ethics, history, reporting, fraud, meta-analyses, randomisation, phases, stopping rules etc. - at an advanced undergraduate to early post-grad level.

The few times I was frustrated with it (the 1st edition anyway) where when it lacked sufficient detail - eg the derivations for sample size calculations. A comprehensive starting point!

Answer (score 4):

[Experimental Design for the Life Sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019928511X), by Ruxton & Colegrave, is a nice book and is aimed primarily at undergraduates.

Answer (score 3):

I was using "[Fundamentals of Clinical Trials](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-18539-2)" when I was in PhD program.