# Book on designing clinical trials in oncology

Tags: references, experiment-design, clinical-trials

I would like to have a good idea on how to design clinical trials in oncology. In that issue, I am looking for a compact book that could give me a good overview, with the emphasis on statistical considerations.
Would you have a recommendation for me?

Thank you in advance,
Marco

Comment: @onestop, @Marco, CW?

Comment: @cardinal: CW? What does that mean???

Comment: this may be more appropriate if marked as Community Wiki.

Comment: @cardinal: Oh, OK! But I still cannot create a new tag...

Comment: @ocram can you explain how what you are looking for is different than is found in the general work on clinical trials? The biological details of oncology are nonstatistical in nature, so don't make it a unique question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a very similar question several months back in this post: [Good Text on Clinical Trials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/good-text-on-clinical-trials).

I decided to go with [Clinical Trials: A Methodologic Perspective](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471727814), by Steven Piantadosi I have been incredibly happy with the text. Now it's not aimed at oncology exactly, so this may not be the perfect text for you, but a lot of the fundamentals of clinical trials are addressed in the text, and from there, there are probably scores of journal articles related to oncology trials.

Comment: I would contend that a "good text on clinical trials" is not necessarily a "good text on clinical trials in oncology". Presumably, the interested reader will have already consulted the former, but is interested in more detail on the subjects that come up frequently in oncology: such as PK models, group sequential trials, non inferiority trials, competing risk models. Nonetheless, the OP has suggested that the general text is appropriate, which means (to me) the question should be closed.