# Sample size references

Tags: statistical-significance, references, sample-size

For calculating sample size in clinical research, I have encountered different ways. For example, using lognormal distributions or calculating using ICC. I am confused which method to apply. Could anyone point to the some references to calculate sample size pertaining to clinical research?

Comment: Please provide more details about your own study, as this question is so broad and vague that it could require a book to answer. What type of clinical measurement or outcome is of interest, how many and what types of predictor values do you want to examine, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks! So I am interested in gathering sample size to measure reliability and validity of clinical questionnaire between 2 sets of population. For finding sample size for this situation calculating upper and lower limit of ICC. In another study where we were comparing operative costs between two subgroups, they were being compared using imbalanced and with a lognormal distribution of costs with coefficient of variation. I am not sure when to apply which method. If you can recommend a book, thats fine too

Comment: [This page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2770/28500) has many links to texts on statistics of clinical studies. It's best to consult with a local statistician before you start, as an experienced statistician will more quickly recognize the issues that are most critical for your particular study. Otherwise you may spend a lot of time reading about matters that aren't of immediate importance. That can be good for your education, but bad for your efficiency and the timely, successful completion of your study.

Comment: Thank you so much EdM. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad question and there are books on the subject. [Here is one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1483319547) that many have found accessible.

See also the link [Good text on Clinical Trials?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/good-text-on-clinical-trials)  provided in a comment.

Comment: Does it make sense to close this question as a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/91630/1352 and migrate your answer there? It looks to me like that one could be a reasonable canonical thread on sample size calculation in clinical trials (based on a [short search for threads with the "references" and "sample-size" tags](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references%2bsample-size)).

Comment: @StephanKolassa: Done