# What is a good book on experimental design and data analysis relevant to industrial bakery applications?

Tags: experiment-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended books on experiment design?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/recommended-books-on-experiment-design)

I will be working with three treatments of egg replacers in bakery applications and would like to receive recommendations for the experiment design and data analysis.

Comment: See also this existing question on recommended books on [experimental design](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/recommended-books-on-experiment-design?rq=1); you may wish to indicate whether this existing question meets your needs or whether there is something particular related to bakery/industry applications that leads you to want a separate question.