# How to choose/select an experimental design

Tags: mathematical-statistics, experiment-design

Is there a rule for selecting which experimental design one should carry out? I am new to statistics/ED and sometimes I find myself asking which design is best to use. 
My general guidelines have been (please correct if wrong):

- Use a Plackett Burman (PB) for screening the number of variables
- Use a fractional factorial if you have a large number of variables and cost/money is a factor as well as estimating effects
- Use an orthogonal design if your variables have different number of levels
- Use a full factorial if you do not have a large number of variables

Another sort of guideline I have is from [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section3/pri33.htm). I would like to have some input from members on their approach on this and if they do things differently.

**EDIT**:
As per @Scortchi advice. Assuming you have a study which has 12 variables and another which 6 variables both with 3 levels for each variable. What type of design would you choose for each and why? The way i would approach this is by maybe screening the variables first as a full factorial would be too many cases to run then apply a full or fractional factorial. However I would then ask well why not do a orthogonal straight away. 
From the link i linked to earlier the objective of the design is a consideration so in the context of obtaining an optimal fit if you have +5 you would screen and then run a design, but why not run an orthogonal straight away. 
Hopefully this may be a bit clearer (apologies if the terminology I am using isn't correct)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This is a rather broad question - whole books have been written to answer it (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/recommended-books-on-experiment-design for some of them). Perhaps you could give a specific example, explaining what designs you're considering & what you're unsure about.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach may be good as a start, until you get more experience, at least for your application area (industry/processes?).  But it is impossible to reduce experimental design to such a set of rules, especially if you want them to cover all application areas!  So you should strive for an understanding where you base design on a few important principles, such as

1. replication
2. blocking
3. factorial design/fractional factorials
4. orthogonality
5. confounding

then you will be able to construct a design for your needs. 
Then find a good book from the many mentioned here:  [Recommended books on experiment design?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/recommended-books-on-experiment-design)